# Trouble with parametrizing function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

hope you're all well!

I just started learning about line integrals in class today, and I'm having a difficult time understanding how and why the solution manual came up with the parameterization for the following homework problem:

**Evaluate the integral $\int_{c} y^2 dx+x^2dy$ for the given path, where $C:$ boundary of the region lying between the graphs of $y=x$ and $y=x^2$.**

I understand for the first boundary, $y=x$, we can let $x=t$ and $y=t, 0\leq t \leq 1$.  For the boundary $y=x^2$ the parameterization in the solution manual is $x=1-t, y=(1-t)^2, 0\leq t \leq 1$.

Why can't we let $x=t$ again which would mean $y=t^2$?

Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Best,

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

See this picture for a visualization of what I am talking about.

I think this has to do with the direction we are taking the line integral -- the substitution $1−t$ being necessary to maintain consistency with the convention established by the direction implied by taking $t$ for the other part of the boundary.

The hardest part about line integrals (in my opinion) usually isn't the parametrization so much as it is about making sure to keep track of the directions -- the potential confusion is arguably even greater than that from mixing up minus signs, if you can believe that.